# Orbeon forms - validation trigger on keyup

Tags: validation, orbeon, keyup

We are using Orbeon forms version 2017.1.1, and we are trying to trigger validation of the current field in the form on each keyup JS event. We have tried using ev:event="xxforms-value-changed" but it only fires after the field has "blurred". Is there a way to trigger the validation on keyup event using XML?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value to be updated as users type, without waiting for users to press enter, or for the field to loose the focus, by adding the `incremental="true"` attribute on your `<xf:input>`. This isn't the default as it creates more chatter between the browser and the server, as well as more load on the server, and often isn't necessary.

Comment: This helps somewhat, but... We've noticed the validation for input field on keyup doesn't fire when user lands on that field for the first time, only after he/she revisits that field. Also, we have several elements in the form that are not only input fields, such as `<xf:select1>`, `<fr:number>`... The `incremental="true"` attribute doesn't seem to work on them. Do you have any suggestion as to how to tackle such elements so their validation fires on keyup?

Comment: Our form is not that big and we do not expect to have many users using it at the same time. Having said that we are certainly weighing pros and cons of using validation on keyup event.

Comment: @Damiao You're saying *We've noticed the validation for input field on keyup doesn't fire when user lands on that field for the first time*. What are the steps I should follow to reproduce what you are seeing?

Comment: maybe [this video](https://app.box.com/s/8raha7mlj120jsj6jsa64e355efz8cp5) can better explain what I was referring to

Comment: @Damiao I see what happens, and created issue [#3385](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3385). You can see the discussion there. For now, indeed, given the Form Runner CSS, even if the `xforms-invalid` class is updated as users type, the error won't show until users tab out of the field.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Just another part of my question was if it is possible to use similar logic on other form fields mainly select (dropdown) boxes? Because, again, validation fires only when user tabs/clicks out of the field?

Comment: @Damiao For dropdown, what browser are you seeing this with? I am testing this with Chrome, and even without marking the field as incremental, the new value is sent to the server every time you change the value in the dropdown.

Comment: You're right, it seemed like the validation wasn't firing when user would choose an empty value at the top of the dropdown selectbox, but it actually works as expected. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Damiao Good; and thank you for confirming this. Regarding [#3385](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3385), until this is supported, which most likely we won't get a chance to do for 2017.2, do you have a workaround or are you able to live without it?

Comment: This was just a research task to find out how much effort would it take us to change a form that we have to do some calculations right after the user starts typing, instead of pressing calculate button as it is currently implemented. I can write you in more detail via e-mail (we've had a correspondence few times before) since I don't think this conversation would be beneficial for the rest of the community.

Comment: Yes, certainly @Damiao, feel free to email me.